# $.getJSON scope problem

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, scope, getjson

```
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json?screen_name=' + query1 + '&callback=?', function (data) {
    console.log('JSON data string 1 is: ' + data);
    $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json?screen_name=' + query2 + '&callback=?', function (data1) {
        console.log('JSON data string 2 is: ' + data1);
        f2 = data1;
        f1 = data;
        for (var i = 0; i < f1.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < f2.length; j++) {
                if (f1[i] == f2[j]) { //console.log("Adding f1[i]");
                    common.push(f1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        for (var d = 0; d < common.length; d++) {
            $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?user_id=' + common[d] + '&callback=?', function (data2) {
                $('#content').append('<>img  width="50" height="50" src=' + data2.profile_image_url + '>< 

href="http://www.twitter.com/' + data2.screen_name + '">' + data2.name + '</></>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

in this code basically im getting an array(common[]) that contains all the common followers between two twitter users

but the third $.getJSON call doesnt seem to responding at all

Am i doing something wrong

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: What is $? I don't know which library's documentation to read. http://blog.dorward.me.uk/2009/02/19/the-dollar-function-must-die.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working...the problem was that the url had show.xml ...i just changed it to show.json and it started working

Comment: not sure if you are using FireBug, but you definately should be using it to inspect your DOM and scripts. makes finding these things much easier.

Answer (score 2):

setup a global AJAX error event handler like so, and you can then inspect the error. remember if an error occurs within the context of a jQuery AJAX request then nothing happens outside of the error function. if you are using the $.getJSON method then you must set up the error handler in the $.ajaxSetup method.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(xhr, status, e) {
        console.log(xhr, status, e);
    }
});
```